# How to call an Angular Component using ViewContainerRef

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am referring to this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-1a7mh5?file=app%2Fdynamic.component.ts) Link to understand ViewContainerRef.

However, I want to create a component with proper HTML, .ts and CSS file. In the example, I am referring they have coded the HTML in .ts file itself but my Html is big so I want to keep it in a separate file. 
If I have a separate .ts and HTML file then how can I call them using viewContainerRef.
I would highly appreciate if someone can point to a stackblitz example also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is separate the files you can just use `templateUrl` in the Component.ts and put your template in that file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-component.html'
})
```